# The column name changes after importing the data into R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, csv, import

The first column in my data below is called `ID`. But I wonder why when I import my data into `R`, the first column names is shown as `ï..ID`?

How can can keep `ID` to be the column name?

```
d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/memory.csv")

names(d)

# [1] "ï..ID" "Group" "MP"    "SE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify `check.names = FALSE` in case there are some characters that are unusual

```
d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/memory.csv", check.names = FALSE)

names(d)
#[1] "ID"    "Group" "MP"    "SE"
```

Comment: @rnorouzian For me, I was not able to replicate the issue you mentioned.  Sometimes, the encoding may be a factor

Comment: @rnorouzian you meant in both cases? that would be unusual because it is not checking the column names with `check.names = FALSE`.  It may be an issue in your locale setting

Comment: No worries, I'm just waiting to accept in 12 min.

Comment: @rnorouzian can you please check the locale setting from `sessionInfo()`

Answer (score 0):

Likely the correct solution for this is to check for the encoding of the csv file being read. This can be done by using Notepad++, for example.

The encoding of the file has to be supplied as a string to the `read.csv` function via the `fileEncoding` argument:

```
df <- read.csv("file/path.csv", fileEncoding = "ENCODING_STRING")
```

I am not certain if all possible encoding types are supported, but in my case supplying the correct `"UTF-8-BOM"` encode type fixed the exact problem you presented of `"ï.."` being prepended at the start of the 1st column name. This most likely has something to do with how the file bits are being read depending on the encoding.

I would resort to `check.names = F` or renaming the column in code only if supplying the correct encoding type does not solve the issue.